# How to check numerical precision of my computation of Stieltjes-constants?

Tags: nt.number-theory, approximation-algorithms, riemann-zeta-function

In a thread in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186292/derivatives-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-at-s-0) I proposed an older routine of mine for the efficient computation of coefficients; I use a very similar routine for the quick&dirty computation of the Stieltjes-constants.

This motivated me to try to improve my earlier toy-computations to calculate now the first 512 Stieltjes to 1000 dec digits precision.  I'm unable to estimate the number of correct digits by analytical arguments; at least wolframalpha allowed me to display StieltjesGamma[511] to 400 digits, which met my own computations.

The only freely available table around seems to be that of S. Plouffe (linked via [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants)) but they display only the first 78 numbers to 256 digits precision.

**Update2:** This is the effective formula to which the Pari/GP code reduces:

Let $ \qquad  h_c = {1\over c!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {\ln(1+k)^c\over1+k}$  This is done using the *sumalt*-procedure.

Next let $ \qquad r_c = - {\ln(2)^{c-1}\over c!} b_c$ where $b_c$ are the bernoulli numbers

Then $ \qquad \gamma_c = c! \sum_{d=0}^{c+1} h_d \cdot r_{c+1-d} $

*So my question:*

> how could I possibly get an educated guess for the number of correct digits based on my Pari/GP-routine?*

Alternatively:

> is there some table with comparable precision around such that I can at least check the match for the first m digits (where m should optimally go to 1000)?

*(here is the table with my current computations of [512 coeffs by 1000 digits](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tables/stieltjes_512x1000.zip))*

---

**Update1:**
Heuristically I find, that beginning with some precision, say $300$ dec digits at the first $\gamma_0$ , I simply lose one digit precision per step in the index, so in $\gamma_k$ are roughly $300-k$ digits correct, maybe a handful less.
For this I used differences when computed with precision $200,300,400,500,600,700$ from that with precision $800$, $\gamma_0$ had just nearly all leading digits constant, when precision was increased, so that was always correct to the full precision.
That would mean, that if I want $1000$ correct digits for $\gamma_{511}$ I need dec precision of (at least) $1550$ . Simple, if that is true...

---

Here is my routine. I reduced the precision-parameter so that this can just be copied & pasted to a Pari/GP-environment. For precision of 1000 dec digits and 512 coefficients this must be optimized due to exorbitant increase of stack and computation-time otherwise

Prepare computations with parameters for precision of computation

```
termsforseries = 32
digitstocompute = 200; digitstoshow = 12;
default(realprecision,digitstocompute)
default(format,Str("g0.",digitstoshow))
default(seriesprecision,termsforseries)
```

Compute the coefficients of the Laurent-expansion of the zeta by conversion from the same series-type of the eta-function (the alternating zeta)

```
\\ ========= Zeta Laurent-expansion providing Stieltjes-coefficients ====
ps_eta = sumalt(k=0,taylor((-1)^k/(1+k)^(1-x),x))

    tmp = Vec(1-2*2^(-(1-x)));
    tmp[1]=0; \\ make the first zero exact. this step is needed for
              \\ allowing the reciprocal of the powerseries
ps_etatozeta=1/Ser(tmp)

ps_zeta = ps_eta * ps_etatozeta \\ contains now the Stieltjes-coefficients

    tmp=Vec(ps_zeta);tmp=vector(#tmp-1,c,tmp[1+c]) \\ remove the first coefficient (at 1/x)
sti = vector(#tmp,r,tmp[r]*(r-1)!)  \\ extract Stieltjes-constants by mult with factorials
```

Answer (score 5):

You could compare with the output from mpmath:

```
sage: import mpmath
sage: mpmath.mp.dps = 1000
sage: %time mpmath.stieltjes(511)
CPU times: user 123.17 s, sys: 0.02 s, total: 123.19 s
Wall time: 123.40 s
mpf('673581492593841075447052270498937988033439947306384442967711559788996269245614412865378751092398327114199475672304543519558074203937367354475627304841991475249868411079091195038704370379319922304314968920977080.4218186954910530966341150821211999689800345913062006500416130863993252444286525401536530609127800808358611180051913954061786113778487954768827917318185861285728540852470806490244553130800206629709991267757983837666355484638397085316115099902138453930569718675294835237821298508690226519561229169443578986238598614523990440226172962706436119188515904391443174279895106345752233034115379099381680958168062786627389335290431416199037643058641914376639305675292168558263653044141610653456719446309980037732502545489019580865593535176949757824659484296855986638635532332512794555243036229273521585906314889067495562018805980518215400448131311489588531760771126389926309367463577942595344292677230759234541824332220012416082001221662802813469321335808232095303910714771240349667445255785796410716571')
```

This only seems to agree with your result up to about 715 digits. Mathematica 8 agrees with mpmath, so presumably you will need to increase the precision in your algorithm.

Comment: Ah, thanks; I'll see whether I can find something about the implementation in mpmath. 

Comment: The algorithm is described here: http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/zeta.html#stieltjes

Specifically, it does numerical integration.

Comment: @Fredrik: Well, very nice, indeed! That made it immediately into my bookmarks; thank you very much! I'll see what I can take from it...

Comment: @Fredrik: I added some heuristic for the achievable precision to my original question. 

Comment:   @Fredrik: I've re-computed the 1000-digit version with prec 1600 and uploaded to the given link; the last entry matches now exactly your reference where the last digit is rounded upwards (you have 3 digits more). So I seem to have at least a rough estimate for the lower bound of computational requirements...

Answer (score 2):

I have recently computed a large table of rigorous values of the Stieltjes constants. Thanks to some coding by Jon Bober, the table can be browsed using a web interface on LMFDB.org (the L-functions and modular forms database):

http://beta.lmfdb.org/riemann/stieltjes/

For any $n \le 10^5$, the web interface allows printing $\gamma_n$ to at least 10000 digits (over 30000 digits for small $n$). The raw data (huge files) can also be downloaded.